# Unable to retrieve data in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a question about retrieving data, which is something I am trying to learn and also first time to used it.

> **Error for test failed**: "Test method
>   TestBusinessLogic.MediaDurationBLTest.OpenModelTest threw exception:
>   System.Exception: Unable to retrieve Media Duration Model Another user
>   has already updated the model. Please refresh and try again."

**MediaDurationBLTest.cs**

This is the main method:

```
  [TestMethod()]
        public void OpenModelTest()
        {
            MediaDurationDS mds = new MediaDurationDS();
            PopulateTestDataSet(mds);

            MediaDurationBL target = new MediaDurationBL();
            TestBusinessLogic.BusinessLogic_MediaDurationBLAccessor accessor = new TestBusinessLogic.BusinessLogic_MediaDurationBLAccessor(target);
            //assign accessor to mds
            accessor.mMediaDurationDataSet = mds;

            int modelID = 5514;

            target.OpenModel(modelID);

            Assert.AreEqual(20, mds.Tables.Count, "# of tables retrieved are different");

            //We are creating copy of ProjectMetricData, check if copyTable and original table are same
            //except projectmetrictdata has pf&d and client does not so subtract that.
            int pfanddRows = 2;
            int projectMetricDataRows = accessor.mMediaDurationDataSet.ProjectMetricData.Rows.Count;
            int copiedRows = projectMetricDataRows - pfanddRows;
            if (copiedRows < 0)
                copiedRows = 0;

            Assert.AreEqual(accessor.mMediaDurationDataSet.ClientProjectMetricData.Rows.Count, copiedRows, "project metric data copy not created");

        }
```

This is the inner code of the "*target.OpenModel(modelID)*;", I get the error and straight away jump to "*catch (Exception e)")*, my data was empty at here "*mMediaDurationDataLayer.GetModelDetails(mMediaDurationDataSet, modelID);*", how do I solve the error?

```
public DataSet OpenModel(int modelID)
        {
            try
            {
                mMediaDurationDataSet = new MediaDurationDS();
                mMediaDurationDataLayer.GetModelDetails(mMediaDurationDataSet, modelID);

                //ConvertToLocalTime(mMediaDurationDataSet.Model, "ClientLastUpdateDate");
                ConvertToLocalTime(mMediaDurationDataSet.ModelActivity, "ClientLastUpdateDate");

                //IF MODEL IS MOR, ACT
                CreateProjectForMORModel(modelID);

                //COPY PROJECT METRIC DATA TABLE INTO CLIENTPROJECTMETRICDATA   
                foreach (MediaDurationDS.ProjectMetricDataRow pmdr in mMediaDurationDataSet.ProjectMetricData.Rows)
                {
                    //WE DONT WANT PF&D IN CLIENT TABLE
                    if (!pmdr.MetricTypeName.Equals(PFANDDPARAMETER))
                    {
                        CreateClientProjectMetricDataRow(pmdr, pmdr.ProjectMetricID);
                    }

                }           

                mMediaDurationDataSet.AcceptChanges();
                mMediaDurationDataSet.WriteXml("C:\\MediaDurationTestDataSet.xml");
                return mMediaDurationDataSet;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorMessage = "Unable to retrieve Media Duration Model " +Environment.NewLine + e.Message;
                throw new Exception(errorMessage);
            }
        }



public class MediaDurationDL
{
    ProjectManagerDL mProjectManagerDL;

    public void GetModelDetails(DataSet mediaDurationDataSet, int modelID)
    {
        Database db = X.XXX.WindowsApplicationTemplate.ApplicationDatabase.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

        string sqlProcedure = "uspMediaDurationGetModel";
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlProcedure);
        UtilityDL.SetCommandTimeout(dbCommand);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "ModelID", DbType.Int32, modelID);

        string[] tables = new string[] { "LaborCategory", "ProcessCategory", "Media", "Activity",                   "Time",   "Model", "ModelTime", "ModelActivity", 
         "Project", "ProjectAccess", "MetricType", "ProjectMetric", "ProjectMetricData" };//, "Metric", "MetricData"};

        // RETRIEVE DATA FROM DB AND LOAD INTO DATASET
        mediaDurationDataSet.Clear();
        //PrintAllErrs(mediaDurationDataSet);
        db.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, mediaDurationDataSet, tables);
        //PrintAllErrs(mediaDurationDataSet);
    }
```

I guess there is an incorrect data information in "MediaDurationTestDataSet.xml" file, how do I retrieve the correct ones?

Comment: Show us stack trace at least. There is exception in some of calls inside GetModelDetails method. It's unknown where it thrown, because you hidden it by using `catch` construction. Currently only way to solve this problem is to debug more..

Also, did you understand that what you doing is not unit testing at all?

Comment: I can see 3 model activity data when I use data set visualizer to view the data at line "mMediaDurationDataSet = new MediaDurationDS();", however when I debug this line "mMediaDurationDataLayer.GetModelDetails(mMediaDurationDataSet, modelID);" the data become empty.

Comment: I have posted the "GetModelDetails method".

Comment: It cannot get into the foreach loop...after went through the "GetModelDetails", what should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your exception and that you do this once in your test and once in OpenModel I am thinking you want to access something twice here:

In your test setup:

```
    MediaDurationDS mds = new MediaDurationDS();
    PopulateTestDataSet(mds);
```

In open model:

```
    mMediaDurationDataSet = new MediaDurationDS();
    mMediaDurationDataLayer.GetModelDetails(mMediaDurationDataSet, modelID);
```

As the exception say:

> Unable to retrieve Media Duration Model Another user has already
>   updated the model.

So your PopulateTestDataSet is accessing underlying system and you get exception because it is in use.

Comment: yes...how do I solve this? May you explain more precise? sorry, I am beginner at here.

Comment: Look into `PopulateTestDataSet` and find way to close connection or let go some resource. Do not know what the code really is in `MediaDurationDS` I assume it is some inhouse class.